# MySQL: Searching number column with string parameter

Tags: mysql

Let's say we have a record in table 'orders' with id=1. This query:

```
SELECT * FROM 'orders' WHERE id = 'abc1'
```

won't return mentioned record. But this query:

```
SELECT * FROM 'orders' WHERE id = '1abc'
```

will return the record with id=1. This is because when MySQL converts string to number 'abc1' becomes 0, but '1abc' becomes 1. Is there a nice way to make MySQL search strictly for records with id from query, i.e. not return the record with id=1 in both mentioned cases?

Comment: You could make the `id` as a `varchar` but then it will not serve for the actual purpose of an ID..

Comment: Where does 'abc1' or '1abc' come from and why aren't the search parameters validated and sanitized? What purpose would a query like `SELECT * FROM 'orders' WHERE id = '123IReallyDoNotCareIfThisIsARealNumberOrNot'` serve?

Answer (score 6):

What about using :

```
SELECT * FROM 'orders' WHERE id LIKE '1abc' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

or even

```
SELECT * FROM 'orders' WHERE STRCMP(id, '1abc') = 0;
```

Comment: +1 . . . The advantage of the first method is that it will use an index on `id`.

Comment: Superior to mine indeed, that first one, voting for this due to key usage, deleting mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

I handled it with PHP before submitting the SQL query

```
$idTest = '1abc';
if (is_numeric($id){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM 'orders' WHERE id = '$idTest'"
}
```

This will prevent submitting queries if the `$idTest` has a string